# How to write such $\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}$ in equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, exponentiation, radicals

Is it correct to write $\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}$ as equation/formula? or $\sqrt[4]{x}$?

I mean, for example, if $x = 10000$, the outcome will be $10$.

Comment: One can write it as $x^{1/4}$, or as $\sqrt[4]{x}$; if you are asking about $\LaTeX$ code, the code for the latter is `\sqrt[4]{x}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not *wrong* to write $\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}$ in the same way that it's not *wrong* to write $\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{2x^1}{2}}}$, but it's generally preferable to write expressions as simply as possible.

The phrase "square root" means the same thing as "one-half power". So,

$$
\sqrt{\sqrt{x}} = \sqrt{x^{1/2}} = (x^{1/2})^{1/2} = x^{1/2 \cdot 1/2} = x^{1/4}.
$$

For the same reason as with square root, it would be appropriate to write either $x^{1/4}$ or $\sqrt[4] x$.